# Is it bad practice to add a flag to throw an exception?

Tags: php, exception

I have some methods in a class that I think could be useful for testing stuff, but also in some cases the program may want to halt completely if the check fails. Originally I was wrapping the method calls in if conditions and then throwing an exception, however, I ended up having the same if conditions in many methods and it seemed wasteful, so I added a boolean flag to the check method to have it throw an exception if the check failed. An example:

```
public function isValidDirection($direction, $throwException = false) {
    if(!in_array($direction, $this->getDirections()) && $throwException) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid direction value. Valid directions are: "%s"', implode(", ", $this->getDirections())));
    }    

    return in_array($direction, $this->getDirections());
}
```

Is this a bad idea? I've not come across this kind of pattern before and I'm wondering are there any pitfalls to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exception should be thrown in exceptional circumstances. That means when your code is in a situation that it is not prepared to handle. If your function is a validation function whose job it is to confirm the validity of data, there should hardly be any exceptional error possible. The job of the function is simple: take input, return `true` or `false` depending on whether it's valid. If you want to handle the case of invalid input by throwing an exception and you want to DRY that repetitive check, create another function which wraps your validation function. So you'd have two functions: `isValidDirection($input)` and `assertIsValidDirection($input)`, the latter of which throws an exception if it's not valid and otherwise does nothing.

```
function isValidDirection($input) {
    return ...; // true or false
}

function assertIsValidDirection($input) {
    if (!isValidDirection($input)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException;
    }
}
```

This keeps both functions' responsibilities clear and their implementation simple.

Comment: I like this approach. Can you please clarify what you mean by "DRY that repetitive check"? I get what it means, but what is "DRY"?

Comment: Don't Repeat Yourself

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a bad idea. If the method gets into a state where it can't continue or otherwise shouldn't get into it should throw an exception. It's up to the calling code to handle the exception as it feels is necessary or let the program crash. Otherwise the caller is oblivious to the program failing and will continue and usually make the situation worse/harder to debug.

If, in the case that you don't want to halt your program you can catch the exception and log an error, or handle it some more graceful way depending on your situation. If you don't expect the error at all the program will crash (ideally during testing) and the error won't propagate; you then know exactly where to look to fix it.

So, if I understand it correctly, your code should throw an exception if the `$direction` isn't in `getDirections`.

e.g:

```
public function isValidDirection($direction) {
    if(!in_array($direction, $this->getDirections())) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid direction value. Valid directions are: "%s"', implode(", ", $this->getDirections())));
    }    

    return in_array($direction, $this->getDirections());
}
```

(Also, you don't need to call `getDirections` 3 times, just call it once and store it in a variable)

Comment: So would you recommend I change isValidDirection to _always_ throw an exception? Or should I make it simply return true/false and then throw exceptions in _other_ methods that make use of isValidDirection? In the case of the latter, that results in significant code duplication in the class, but in the case of the former, it feels wrong that isValidDirection should throw an exception, since the point of it is to take _any_ direction, then tell you if it is valid or not.

Comment: No, definitely don't always throw an exception. I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Well, I think a method called isValidDirection should return true/false. In your example it will _only_ return true when it is in the array (which would mean the final return could simply be return true, right?) convince me that this is a good idea. I feel like it should return true if it's a valid direction, and false if it isn't. Passing a incorrect direction doesn't seem like something that could be considered fatal, at least not for this method.